# UIButton title disappears

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uibutton

I have a ViewController with an UIButton inside.
When I clicked, the text on the button disappeared.
I add all the setTitle for all states, but it continues disappearing.
Any idea?

This is a part of my code:

```
@interface AddCardViewController : UITableViewController <UITextFieldDelegate>{
UIButton *commit;
    ......

@implementation AddCardViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad{

    self.commit = [UIButton buttonWithType: UIButtonTypeCustom];

    [self setCommitProperties];

    [self.view addSubview:commit];

 .........}



- (void) setCommitProperties{

   CGRect frameTable = self.tableView.frame;

   CGRect frame = CGRectMake(frameTable.origin.x + 10, 140, frameTable.size.width - 20, 40);

   commit.frame = frame;

   [commit setBackgroundColor : [UIColor whiteColor]];

   [commit setTitle: NSLocalizedString(@"AddCard",@"") forState: UIControlStateNormal];
   [commit setTitle: NSLocalizedString(@"AddCard",@"") forState: UIControlStateSelected];
   [commit setTitle: NSLocalizedString(@"AddCard",@"") forState: UIControlStateHighlighted];
   [commit setTitle: NSLocalizedString(@"AddCard",@"") forState: UIControlStateApplication];
   [commit setTitle: NSLocalizedString(@"AddCard",@"") forState: UIControlStateReserved];
   [commit setTitle: NSLocalizedString(@"AddCard",@"") forState: UIControlStateDisabled];

    [commit addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];    

   UIColor *color = [[[PersonalizationManager alloc] init] getColor: @"AddCardViewController" :@"Commit_Title"]; 

   [commit.titleLabel setTextColor: color];

   color = [[[PersonalizationManager alloc] init] getColor: @"AddCardViewController" :@"Commit_Border"];

   [commit.layer setBorderColor:[color CGColor]];    
   [commit.layer setBorderWidth : 0.5f];
   [commit.layer setCornerRadius : 10.0f];
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well it's hard to say for sure, but is the text not visible because the color is the same? I see you set the text for all states but you may want to set the color for all states as well.

```
[commit setTextColor:[UIColor redColor] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
```

Comment: Yeah!, that was the solution. You are right.
I didn't think about the color, I tried and tested all over the Title's properties.
Those are the good things of ask.
Thank you very much

Comment: I am a new ios developer and I think the api is changed cz there is no setTextColor method available. Use setTitleColor instead

Answer (score 4):

With attributed text, make sure button Type = **Custom** (not System) in your storboard/xib.

Comment: Thanks @david. this worked for me. but why does it work??

Answer (score 2):

I noticed a peculiar thing. 
If I set the title using

```
  bttn.titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor purpleColor];
```

Then as soon as I click the button, the title disappears.
But, if I use the following method :

```
[bttn setTitleColor:[UIColor purpleColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Then everything is working correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you need to use `[self.commit setTitle: NSLocal...`, actually use self.commit overall for assignments (when you use `@property (nonatomic, retain)` or `strong` with ARC). I use `@synthesize commit = _commit;` and then only _commit for all the rest of the module.

Answer (score 0):

As Jack says, it's the "selected" state of the button that has got the same color of the background.
You can change that color also in the Storyboard:

- select the button
- in Attributes Inspector -> State Config -> select "highlighted"
- select the correct "text color"